# React.cloneElement and Duplicating React Elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a function which takes in a react element/component.

I wanted to create a copy of this argument and make changes to it that wouldn't affect the original element. Here is a sample of the code:

```
function displayNameChanger(element) {
    let tempElement = React.cloneElement(element);

    console.log(element);

    tempElement.displayName = "New Name";
    ...
}
```

Despite logging the original element, I find that the console.log shows that the displayName is "New Name" which doesn't make sense to me. I thought React.cloneElement creates and **returns** a new copy of the element that I can make changes to without affecting the original but it seems to not be the case.

Can anyone explain to me whats going on and how I can make a copy of an element and change its displayName without affecting the original element?

Comment: and what's your element which you wanna clone?

Comment: React.cloneElement is works only if cloned element has single children. If you want to change some properties of cloned element, you can pass a second param: `return React.cloneElement(element, {newProp});

Comment: I'm trying to clone custom functional components. Ex: Accent or Ellipsis.

Here is one such object I am attempting to clone in JSX format:
<Accent> <Ellipsis> this </Ellipsis> </Accent> <Accent> is a title </Accent>